# Start a function in future

Tags: python, timer, future

I want to launch a particular function (taking an argument) after 2 seconds.
I've tried the following code, but my problem is, I'm unable to pass the argument to my function.

```
from threading import Timer
import time

def done(t):  # Unable to pass argment - t
    print t

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print 'first'
    t = Timer(2, done)
    t.start()
```

Can someone please help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what `args` and `kwargs` arguments are for ([see docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Timer)):

```
t = Timer(2, done, args=[whatever_value_you_need])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try `functools.partial` as well as `lambda`.

```
from threading import Timer
from functools import partial


def done(t):
    print t


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print 'first'
    t = Timer(2, partial(done, 'second'))
    t.start()
    t = Timer(2, lambda: done('third'))
    t.start()
```